# javascirpt return TypeError: undefined Error

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm executing this code, although it produces an error.

```
function getUserPosts(){
  $.get("../php/PostHandler.php", function(data) {
    var posts = JSON.parse(data);
    alert(posts);
    for(var x = lastNumPosts; x <= posts.length; x++){
      var postLine = "<div class='user-post'><div class='user-p-info'><img src='imgs/email-icon2.png'><h2> "+ posts[x].name  +" </h2><br> <small>Posted Tuesday 23/10</small></div><div class='user-p-content'><p>" + posts[x].pContent + "</p></div></div>";
      $('.post-zone').prepend(postLine);
    }
  });
}
```

> TypeError: posts[x] is undefined

Any solutions?

Comment: `x < posts.length`

Comment: please provide the response data  produced by the call

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change this line:

```
for (var x = lastNumPosts; x < posts.length; x++) {
```

Notice the `<` instead of `<=`.

Comment: Legend :) Thank you

Comment: Just to be clear, the reason this works is because using `<=`  allows the value of `x` to go above the extents of the `posts` array